# Adding Web page to iFrame when a web user control event fires

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webusercontrol

i am new to aspx programming,
I have a web page say default.aspx, and i am using two web user control on the page namely 
usercontrol1 and usercontrol2
now i am having an i frame on default page. I am having buttons on usercontrol2 which on the click opens up a page namely default2.aspx. it works fine. the problem is that i want to open default2 page inside default page's iframe when the button click event is fired from usercontrol2 buttons.
thanks in advance
reema

Answer (score 0):

You must write javascript for this situation. And call this function button's onClientClick event.